# How to add a vertical plot line in multiple line series and show the tooltip on Plot line in highchart

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I am trying to add a plotline on click in multiple series line chart in reactjs. I am using stockchart of high chart,  Please let me know how to add plotline with tooltip.
Sample Screenshot: [image]

Comment: Any screenshot or demo for your demand?

Comment: @keikai I have added a screenshot. I have an yAxis crosshair and need a plotline on click in multiple series line chart. Let me know if you need any more details.

Answer (score 0):

I prepared a demo which shows how to add the **plotLine** dynamically with the custom tooltip.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lyr82a5x/

```
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  chart.xAxis[0].addPlotLine({
    value: 5.5,
    color: 'red',
    width: 2,
    id: 'plot-line-1',
    events: {
      mouseover() {
        let lineBBox = this.svgElem.getBBox();

        tooltip.style.display = 'block';
        tooltip.style.left = lineBBox.x + 'px';
      },
      mouseout() {
        tooltip.style.display = 'none'
      }
    }
  })
})
```

If something is unclear - feel free to ask.

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.plotLines.events.mouseout

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#addPlotLine

Comment: What do you mean? The tooltip which has a plotLine inside?